# Django ModelChoiceField - select option via JQuery without removing options

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form like so:

```
class ProjectInfoForm(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Module.objects.all().order_by('name'),
    )
    ...
```

And in my template I have some jQuery which I want to use for selecting an option form the module dropdown:

```
  $('#id_module').append('<option value="foo" selected="selected">Foo</option>');
```

However, this actually removes all the original options, which I want to be still available. So I want to select `FOO` but have the other options available in the drop down below `FOO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select an existing option you can use the following:

```
$('#id_module').find('option[value="foo"]').attr('selected', true);
```